# String length() comparison is not working properly

Tags: java

```
public class LongWord {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String text = "my brother is taller than me@1233334. I always a short man,but smart than him";

        // Find the longest word in the String
        String[] words = text.split("\\s");
        String longestWord = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
            int firstLen = words[i - 1].length();
            int secondLen = words[i].length();
            if (firstLen <= secondLen) {
                longestWord = words[i];
            }
        }
        System.out
                .println("===================================================\nLongest Word:::: \n");
        System.out.println(longestWord);
    }
}
```

// This is the sample program to find the longest word in the statement. so the output should be "me@1233334" word. but I am getting "man,but" word as output. can anyone please help me what is wrong with program.

Comment: Execute your algorithm with a pen, on a peper, and write each variable value at each step. You have a basic logic isssue.

Comment: Especially focus on the length of the words you are comparing.

Comment: You might want to look into another java class named StringTokenizer.  With it you can specify which delimiters to use such as spaces, and commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method doesn't find the largest string in an array of strings. It finds the last string in an array of strings which is larger than the string directly before it.

Your comparison `(firstLen <= secondLen)` doesn't compare either of the strings to the current longest string. Your main loop should be:

```
String longestWord = words[0];
for(String word : words) {
  if(word.length() > longestWord.length()){
    longestWord = word;
  }
}
```

You can also use `for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)` and use `words[i]` instead of `(String word : words)` and `word`

Answer (score 0):

The logic for deciding the longest word is wrong.

You are comparing a "word" (in this context, word just means something separated by a white space) with the previous word, and if it is longer, that is now the longest.

man,but is selected because it is simply longer than its previous word (short). Note that nothing after man,but is selected because no words after that are longer than their previous word

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong. You aren't comparing if the `secondLen` is bigger than `longestWord`, it should actually be:

```
longestWord = words[0];
for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    int longestLen = longestWord.length();
    int secondLen = words[i].length();
    if (longestLen <= secondLen) {
        longestWord = words[i];
    }
}
```